# Ramda: Filtering through arrays with associated value

Tags: ramda.js

This is my initial dataset:

```
arr1 = [{
      url: ['https://example.com/A.jpg?', 'https://example.com/B.jpg?', 'https://example.com/C.jpg?'], 
      width: ['w=300', 'w=400', 'w=500'], 
      type: [-1, 1, 2]
     }];
```

By filtering with `type: n => n > 0` and passing the result through the `arr1`, I would like to  produce `arr2` with Ramda. If `n`th value is excluded as the result of the filter, then `n`th value in another arrays are also excluded.

```
arr2 = [{
      url: ['https://example.com/B.jpg?', 'https://example.com/C.jpg?'], 
      width: ['w=400', 'w=500'], 
      type: [1, 2]
     }];
```

I tried the code below, but not working...

```
const isgt0 =  n => n > 0 ;

const arr2 = R.applySpec({
url : arr1,
width : arr1,
type :  R.filter(isgt0),
});

console.log(arr2(arr1));
```

Once I get the desired object, I intend to `R.transpose` the array to generate an URL like:  `[https://example.com/B.jpg?w=400, https://example.com/C.jpg?w=500]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main steps are:

Get the arrays of the values with R.props:

- `[-1, 1, 2]`
- `['w=300', 'w=400', 'w=500']`
- `['https://example.com/A.jpg?', 'https://example.com/B.jpg?', 'https://example.com/C.jpg?']`

Transpose them to arrays of items with the same index:

- `[-1, 'w=300', 'https://example.com/A.jpg?']`
- `[1, 'w=400', 'https://example.com/B.jpg?']`
- `[1, 'w=500', 'https://example.com/C.jpg?']`

Filter by index `0` (the original `type`), transpose back, and then reconstruct the object using R.applySpec.

```js
const { pipe, props, transpose, filter, propSatisfies, gt, __, tranpose, applySpec, nth, map } = R

const filterProps = pipe(
  props(['type', 'width', 'url']), // get an array of property
  transpose, // convert to arrays of all property values with the same index
  filter(propSatisfies(gt(__, 0), 0)), // filter by the type (index 0)
  transpose, // convert back to arrays of each type
  applySpec({ // reconstruct the object
    type: nth(0),
    width: nth(1),
    url: nth(2),
  })
)

const data = [
  {
    type: [-1, 1, 2],
    width: ['w=300', 'w=400', 'w=500'],
    url: [
      'https://example.com/A.jpg?', 
      'https://example.com/B.jpg?', 
      'https://example.com/C.jpg?',
    ],
  }
]

const result = map(filterProps, data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to think about it more generically is to filter using a configuration object that holds the tests to apply for various properties.  Here it is only `type`, but it's easy enough to imagine others.

My solution for this problem is configured with this object:

```js
{
    type: n => n > 0
}
```

This solutions uses many Ramda functions, but also uses `Array.prototype.filter` to have access to the index parameter of `filter`.  We could choose `R.addIndex` instead, but I would only bother if I was trying to make it point-free, which doesn't seem worthwhile here.  This is what it might look like:

```js
const filterOnProps = (config) => (obj) => {
  const test = allPass (map(([k, v]) => (i) => v (obj [k] [i]), toPairs (config)))
  const indices = filter (test) (range (0, values (obj) [0] .length))
  return map(a => a .filter ((_, i) => contains (i, indices)), obj)
}

const transform =  map (filterOnProps ({type: n => n > 0}))

const arr1 = [{url: ['https://example.com/A.jpg?', 'https://example.com/B.jpg?', 'https://example.com/C.jpg?'], width: ['w=300', 'w=400', 'w=500'], type: [-1, 1, 2]}]

console .log (transform (arr1))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {allPass, map, toPairs, filter, range, values, contains} = R    </script>
```

With `obj` in scope, we create `test`, which will be somewhat equivalent to

```js
allPass([
    i => obj['type'][i] > 0
])
```

If we had more conditions in the original configuration object, they would also be in this list.

Then we filter the indices, to see on which ones the record passes this test.

Finally we map over our object, filtering each array to keep only those where the index is in the list.

---

While this should work, and is reasonably generic, it points to a problem with your data structure.  I would suggest that as much as possible, you shy away from situations where structures are dependent on shared indices.  To my mind the only reasonable use of that is for a relatively compact serialization format.  On deserialization, I would immediately rehydrate that to something more useful, perhaps something like

```js
const data = [
    {url: 'https://example.com/A.jpg?', width: 'w=300', type: -1}, 
    {url: 'https://example.com/B.jpg?', width: 'w=400', type: 1},
    {url: 'https://example.com/C.jpg?', width: 'w=500', type: 2}
]
```

This structure is much easier to work with.  For example, `data.filter(({type}) => type > 0)` would be the equivalent to the work above, if you started with this structure.

Comment: I think I would rehydrate the data structure like the above. Problem does not even exist if I start right. That makes life easier after all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might help a bit

```js
const gte1 = R.filter(R.gte(R.__, 1));

const fn = R.map(
  R.evolve({
    type: gte1,
  }),
);


// =====

const data = [
  {
    type: [-1, 1, 2],
    width: ['w=300', 'w=400', 'w=500'],
    url: [
      'https://example.com/A.jpg?', 
      'https://example.com/B.jpg?', 
      'https://example.com/C.jpg?',
    ],
  }
];

console.log(
  fn(data),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem as stated. Your `url` and `width` result still have the undesirable data.